# Need to create this JavaScript regex to extract the word in the pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

Need a JavaScript regex to extract the word in the pattern: `;#OPD;#`. In this pattern `OPD` is the word that must be extracted.

```
var str = ";#OPD;#" ;
```

What is the regex to get `OPD`?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter? What does your best effort look like? People are more than happy to *help* you, but it's best not to actually ask them to write it *for* you.

Comment: Accept answer for your recent question.

Comment: There a ton of regex questions on here... NONE of them helped you?

Answer (score 4):

A very simple regex:

```
/;#(.*);#/
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rJHHq/

Comment: My bad, blame my habit with PHP regex.